# Shortcut key to isolate a material in the shader editor

Tags: shader-nodes

I've seen this in dozens of tutorials, but what is the keyboard shortcut for previewing a specific node in a shader node tree?

Answer (score 1):

To preview a node, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on the node you want to view, given that *Node Wrangler* addon is enabled and *Use Nodes* is ticked.